# How do you get Taxonomy ID (TID) from a term name via PHP?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Yes, I googled. I searched. No one has a concise answer to this basic question. Everyone seems to be looking for TID to Term name, but not the other way around. And linking to the Drupal API doesnt help neither. A PHP example would seal the deal.

We just need a simple PHP example of how to convert a Term Name to a TID.

I have the following, but it does not work:

```
$tid = _taxonomy_get_tid_from_term($row->field_term_name);

print $tid;
```